# Can the segmented function display its domain of a function completely?

Tags: functions

```
In[10]:= Floor[x Floor[x]] // PiecewiseExpand[#, 0 <= x <= 4, Reals] &
```

[image]

Can 'true' be automatically generated as the corresponding x range: 0<=x<1

Comment: It works the other way round, your function, f[x] will return 0 for x!= 1,4,5,9,10,11,16. True means "if none of the above"